# Get custom object of expression<model, property>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, lambda

I created a custom `TextBoxFor` method to ease my development in razor, using a custom "InputField" class on my ViewModel.

**ViewModel**

```
public enum FieldState
{
    NORMAL,
    DISABLED
}

public class InputField
{
    public FieldState State
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public InputField()
    {
        State = FieldState.NORMAL;
        Value = string.Empty;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(InputField field_)
    {
        return field_.Value ?? string.Empty;
    }
}

public class PrintJobForm
{
    public InputField Material
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

**Extensions**

```
public static MvcHtmlString ClassedTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html_,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expr_,
    string classes_ = "")
    where TProperty : InputField
{
    classes_ += " form-control";

    if (expr_.Compile().Invoke().State == FieldState.DISABLED) {
        classes_ += " disabled";
    }

    return html_.TextBoxFor(expr_, new {
        @class = classes_
    });
}
```

**Form.cshtml**

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.ClassedTextBoxFor(model_ => model_.Material)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model_ => model_.Material)
    </div>
</div>
```

I think what I want to do is pretty straight forward. The current problem is this line

```
if (expr_.Compile().Invoke().State == FieldState.DISABLED) {
    classes_ += " disabled";
}
```

The `Invoke()` requires an argument of type `TModel`. How can I get this from the expression, so I can correctly set the "disabled" state in HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current instance of model passed to view is in`html_`:

```
TModel model = html_.ViewData.Model;
```

So you can use it in your `Invoke`:

```
expr_.Compile().Invoke(model).State
```